# Do questions/answers marked community wiki under the new system qualify for good/great badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

Hello metapeople,

I have a question, possibly related to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16750/how-do-questions-marked-community-wiki-after-you-answer-impact-rep-upon-recalc), but for badges. Everyone knows community wiki has changed, but if I have a question I've asked, that I asked to be converted to community wiki, does it earn badges should it exceed the relevant rep cap?

I guess the natural extension is "do answers marked as community wiki" earn badges, also?

The badge descriptions to me don't explain - they just say "a question/answer". I'm *guessing* non-community q/as apply only.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is rather the same as [this earlier inquiry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56075/how-to-get-question-badges-in-cw-mode), but the system did change, and with it how Community Wiki affects badges. Not the ones you asked about, though.

**Badges like Nice/Good/Great Question/Answer can be awarded to Community Wiki posts**. This is because Community Wiki only stops reputation, not post score, and those badges only care about post score. The new system has not affected this.

---

Technically, badges still don't care about Community Wiki *directly*. The only badges that are affected by Community Wiki are the ones like Epic (dependent on reputation caps that you can't hit on wiki posts), as well as the Generalist and tag specialist badges (dependent on tag score, which [disregards all votes on community wiki posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52754/how-is-the-score-on-the-top-users-page-calculated/52792#52792)). Well, actually, Generalist and the tag specialist badges do specifically mention the "non-wiki" clause, but that strikes more of a formality than as if it were an extra special requirement. The criteria just to award them already implicitly requires posts to be non-wiki.

Recent in this is that specialist badges awarded for performance in tags *are now revoked if you drop below it*. This means that if you were to get those badges, but then some of your posts were turned CW to the point that you no longer qualified, you would lose those badges.

Comment: Wow, that revocation sucks, they should still be counting the votes before it turned CW, and obviously they have the ability to do that, since they keep the votes rep from before it turned CW.

Comment: @Lance Actually, post score for the purposes of Top Users never counted votes from before the post turned CW. Reputation is separate from post score in the end, and all these things care about is the post score.

Comment: I actually like the idea of revocation for specialist badges. I have no justification for liking it, I just do.